# How to display the all files of a selected folder like Explorer in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create Windows Explorer and I have a navigation window which displays folder structure.
What I want to implement next is, all files including subfolders within a selected folder on the nativation window be displayed in a blue area ("viewWindow") but I'm not sure how.
My guess is I need to create a listener which ditects a mouse click and it does, it displays all files.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class fileViewer extends JFrame {
    private static int screenWidth = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    private static int screenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    private static FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    private JSplitPane panel;

    public fileViewer() {
        JTree tree = new JTree(new FileTreeNode(File.listRoots()));
        tree.setCellRenderer(new RenderFileCell());
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        JScrollPane navigationWindow = new JScrollPane(tree);
        JPanel viewWindow = new JPanel();
        viewWindow.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, navigationWindow, viewWindow);
        panel.setDividerLocation(100);
        add(panel);
    }

    // to render the single file cell
    public static class RenderFileCell extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
        private Map<String, Icon> iconCache = new HashMap<>();
        private Map<File, String> rootNameCache = new HashMap<>();

        public RenderFileCell() {
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
                boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

            JLabel result = null;
            FileTreeNode ftn = (FileTreeNode) value;
            File file = ftn.file;
            String fileName = "";

            if (file != null) {
                if (ftn.isFileSystemRoot) {
                    fileName = this.rootNameCache.get(file);
                    if (fileName == null) {
                        fileName = fsv.getSystemDisplayName(file);
                        this.rootNameCache.put(file, fileName);
                    }
                } else {
                    fileName = file.getName();
                }
            }

            result = (JLabel) super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                    tree, fileName, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

            if (file != null) {
                Icon icon = iconCache.get(fileName);
                if (icon == null) {
                    icon = fsv.getSystemIcon(file);
                    iconCache.put(fileName, icon);
                }
                result.setIcon(icon);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    private static class FileTreeNode implements TreeNode {
        private File file;
        private TreeNode parent;
        private File[] children;
        private boolean isFileSystemRoot;

        public FileTreeNode(File[] children) {
            file = null;
            parent = null;
            this.children = children;
        }

        public FileTreeNode(File file, boolean isFileSystemRoot, TreeNode parent) {
            this.file = file;
            this.isFileSystemRoot = isFileSystemRoot;
            this.parent = parent;
            children = this.file.listFiles();
            if (children == null) {
                children = new File[0];
            }
        }

        @Override
        public TreeNode getChildAt(int childIndex) {
            return new FileTreeNode(children[childIndex], parent == null, this);
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildCount() {
            return children.length;
        }

        @Override
        public TreeNode getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIndex(TreeNode node) {
            FileTreeNode ftn = (FileTreeNode) node;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                if (ftn.file.equals(children[i])) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getAllowsChildren() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf() {
            return getChildCount() == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<? extends TreeNode> children() {
            final int elementCount = this.children.length;
            return ((Enumeration<? extends TreeNode>) new Enumeration<File>() {
                int count = 0;

                @Override
                public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                    return count < elementCount;
                }

                @Override
                public File nextElement() {
                    if (count < elementCount) {
                        return FileTreeNode.this.children[count++];
                    }
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
                }

            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new fileViewer();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (screenHeight / 2 * 1.414), screenHeight / 2);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the [FileBro](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me so I can't see its current behaviour. You can also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43560771/131872 for a more basic example. *What I want to implement next is...* - from the above example I guess you could use the "treeWillExpand" event to create the file listing in your blue area.

Comment: `return ((Enumeration<? extends TreeNode>) new Enumeration<File>()` ← That is not how types work.  A File is not a TreeNode.  A File cannot be cast to a TreeNode.  An enumeration of Files cannot be cast to an enumeration of TreeNodes.  You need to actually create TreeNodes (or FileTreeNodes) and return an enumeration of those.